# Union doesnt preserve order(not stable)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I execute below query and expecting first set then second set distinctly but order is totally random.
I expected results: john,mark,dave,robert,kirk

```
select *
from (
    select Name
    from (values ('john'),('mark'),('dave')) X(Name)
    union
    select Name
    from (values ('robert'),('mark'),('kirk')) X(Name)
) q
```

This is alternative query which i expected to have ordered(stable) results but i get same results. Union All append second set as i expected but applying Distinct later break ordering.

```
select Distinct Name
from (
    select Name
    from (values ('john'),('mark'),('dave')) X(Name)
    union all
    select Name
    from (values ('robert'),('mark'),('kirk')) X(Name)
) q
```

What is solution for having ordered and distinct set ?

Comment: add an `order by`. Without an order by, order by is not guaranteed

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid it is not so simple as it seems. I dont want ordered results. I want distinctly combined result.

Comment: use `union` rather than `union all` for a distinct set. If you want to preserve the two entire sets order (i.e. first set on top of second  set) then you first need to decide if there is a duplicate, which set do you want it taken out of?

Comment: For example in your first example, why is mark taken out of the second set, not the first set? Whats the rule - is the rule "always take duplicates out of the second set"

Comment: Use a ranking function and add to the lower set by the amount of rows in the fiist...or whatever works tp enforce the order. You may even consider using a durable key, but i would venture to say we are missing the requirements that lead to an order in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH q AS
(
    -- Original data
    SELECT Name FROM (VALUES ('john'),('mark'),('dave')) X(Name)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Name FROM (VALUES ('robert'),('mark'),('kirk')) X(Name)
), r AS
(
    -- Add the sequence column for ordering
    -- ** It just use natual order **
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Seq, * from q
), s AS
( 
    -- Use RN to filter out the duplicates
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Seq) AS RN FROM r
)
SELECT Name FROM s WHERE RN = 1 ORDER BY Seq
```

Comment: This seems best answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first set first, then every element in the second set that is not in the first set later, then you have to specify it. And you will also need to add an ORDER BY if you want to guarantee things in the first set being listed before the second set.

```
select q.name
from (
    select Name,n
    from 
    (values ('john'),('mark'),('dave')) X(Name)
    cross join (values (1)) y(n)

    union all

    select Name,n
    from
    (
    select Name
    from (values ('robert'),('mark'),('kirk')) X(Name)

    except

    select Name 
    from
    (values ('john'),('mark'),('dave')) X(Name)

    ) Z(Name)
    Cross join (values (2)) y(n)

) q
order by q.n
```

Answer (score 0):

If we are using values to select data then no need to use order by clause and and we won't have to worry about potential index changes from that particular query,so you will have the order always and moreover we are using union all it will just concatenate the result set is not sorted.

However, if you are using table, yes, the order can most certainly change  depends on several factors such as table indexes, columns being returned, new data being introduced, etc. So if you want your results ordered in a particular way, you need to specify ORDER BY clause .

For your example you don't need to use order by clause like below

```
select  Name
from (
    select Name
    from (values ('john'),('mark'),('dave')) X(Name)
    union all

   ( select Name
    from (values ('robert'),('mark'),('kirk')) X(Name)
    except
    select Name
    from (values ('john'),('mark'),('dave')) X(Name))

) q
```

Answer (score -1):

Is it reasonable for you to add a SortOrder column to your inner `SELECT` statements and then order by that? Something like:

```
select Distinct Name
from (
    select SortOrder, Name
    from (values (1, 'john'),(2, 'mark'),(3, 'dave')) X(SortOrder, Name)
    union all
    select SortOrder, Name
    from (values (4, 'robert'),(2, 'mark'),(5, 'kirk')) X(SortOrder, Name)
) q
order by SortOrder ASC
```

Comment: from clauses will be replaced with real tables so this is not accepted answer. If these are fixed data so simply i can manually sort them distinctly.

Answer (score -1):

The only way to guarantee order is by using ORDER BY clause, this is documented in BOL:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx

> Order the result set of a query by the specified column list and, optionally, limit the rows returned to a specified range. The order in which rows are returned in a result set are not guaranteed unless an ORDER BY clause is specified.

If you want rows returned based on order in the UNION, then you could do something like this:

```
select Name
from (
    select 1 as sort1, Name
    from (values ('john'),('mark'),('dave')) X(Name)
    union
    select 2 as sort1, Name
    from (values ('robert'),('mark'),('kirk')) X(Name)
) q
order by sort1, Name
```

Comment: You are even sorting Name so it is still not what expected to get. Please see the expected results.

Comment: Secondly results are not distinct.